# Softlayer API, transaction status of Global IP route/unroute

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can somebody shines some light on the following problem.

We use REST API to route/unroute global IPs.
The response on the following queries are always "null", it is a bug?

hxxxs://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/5555555/unroute
hxxxs://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/5555555/route
{"parameters": ["55.55.55.55"]}

As route and unroute requests initiate a transaction, how I can get status of the transaction to be sure that the process is fully finished?

Based on SLDN (http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/getActiveTransaction) page and REST Article (https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Rest), the request must be:

hxxxs://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/ActiveTransaction.json

But it does not work. I got following response:
`{"error":"Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global::getActiveTransaction)","code":"SoftLayer_Exception"}`

Can you help me, find out a full URL to API method with required parameters?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the response null returned by unroute and route methods is an issue you could submit a ticket in softlayer in oder they fix that issue.

in regards how to get transaction, I am able to get the transacction using the method SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global::getActiveTransaction, I think you are getting the error becuase you are missing the init parameter in  the call. Your call should be something like this:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/$GlobalIPID/getActiveTransaction

Note: replace $GlobalIPID
```

Regards

Comment: You request helped me.Softlayer Support also told, if the transaction is finished, the response is "null".